# Non exclusive or operator to generate new parsing expressions for a Parsing Expression Grammar (PEG)

Tags: python, regex, parsing, grammar

I am writing a PEG containing the following three parsing expressions:

```
int     => ^[-+]?[1-9]\d*
frac    => ^[-+]?[.][0]?[1-9]\d*
exp     => ^[E][1-9]\d*
```

(`exp` stands for the "E notation"). These three expression are used to make up a number. Currently I am writing the parsing expression for `number` as:

```
number  => int frac exp | int frac | int exp | frac exp | int | frac
```

I do not like this definition aesthetically  because I find it repetitive. I would like to shorten it. I imagine the following notation:

```
number   => (int or frac) exp | (int or frac).
```

With this expression, I mean that if `int` or `frac` exists (in the non-exclusive meaning of or) a `exp` follows in the first alternative.  Is there indeed a legitimate way to shorten the definition? Would such a thing violate the principles of a PEG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define `number` in terms of another term, such as `decimal`:

```
decimal   => int frac | int | frac
number    => decimal exp | decimal
```